# Erro ao usar as funções lower(), upper() e title()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estou com o seguinte problema, ao tentar usar as funções `lower()`, `title()` e `upper()`.

Meu compilador simplesmente não permite e exibe o erro

```
AttributeError:'list' object has no attribute'upper'
```

Segue o código:

```
bomdia = ["list"]
bomdia2 = ["LIST"]

print(bomdia.upper())#AttributeError:'list' object has no attribute'upper'
print(bomdia2.lower())#AttributeError:'list' object has no attribute'lower'
print(bomdia.title())#AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu erro é estar declarando como uma lista as variáveis `bomdia` e `bomdia2`

Ao declarar dessa forma você está declarando uma lista de string's e os métodos upper, lower e title são métodos de string, por isso o erro `#AttributeError:'list' object has no attribute'upper'`.

Você pode resolver seu erro dessas 2 formas:

- Continuar declarando como listas e acessar a string dentro dessa lista:

  ```
  bomdia = ["list"]
  bomdia2 = ["LIST"]

  print(bomdia[0].upper())
  print(bomdia2[0].lower())
  print(bomdia[0].title())
  ```
- Declarar as variáveis como string

  ```
  bomdia = "list"
  bomdia2 = "LIST"

  print(bomdia.upper())
  print(bomdia2.lower())
  print(bomdia.title())
  ```